# NSFetchedResultsController returning nil for indexPathForObject

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsindexpath

I have my `FetchedResultsController` (FRC) set up like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MTWMeeting" inManagedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"meetingDay.dayTimestamp" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"meetingTimestamp" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sort, sort2]];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"meetingDay.dayTimestamp" cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
```

My DB is deadly simple - I have a `MTWMeeting` entity and a `MTWDay` entity that can have many meetings. Each meeting can have only 1 parent day.

My table view is setup with headers by 1 `MTWDay` entity for 1 section.

Now I need to scroll to a specific index in that cell.

I'm doing it like this:

```
MTWDay *targetDay = [MTWCoreDataManager suitableDayForMeetingWithTimestamp:[date timeIntervalSince1970]];
MTWMeeting *ourMeeting = [targetDay.dayMeetings anyObject];

NSIndexPath *ourPath = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:ourMeeting];
NSIndexPath *tmpPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:ourPath.section];
```

Now, no matter what I do, `ourPath`index path is always `nil`. However, `MTWDay` and `MTWMeeting` objects are real Core Data objects that I get from the core data stack.

What are my steps to get out of this behaviour? I've been struggling with this issue for days without any chance.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example printout of the `ourMeeting` Core Data object used in the code above:

```
<MTWDay: 0x1742a8d00> (entity: MTWDay; id: 0xd000000001780008 <x-coredata://B0F694E1-7A45-4D1E-BB26-6F0A929A135D/MTWDay/p94> ; data: {
    dayDisplayTitle = "\U0432\U043e\U0441\U043a\U0440\U0435\U0441\U0435\U043d\U044c\U0435";
    dayEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x170230da0 'dayEvents'>";
    dayID = nil;
    dayMeetings =     (
        "0xd000000003440002 <x-coredata://B0F694E1-7A45-4D1E-BB26-6F0A929A135D/MTWMeeting/p209>"
    );
    dayNumericID = 16;
    dayTimestamp = "1.416089e+09";
    daysMonth = "0xd000000000140006 <x-coredata://B0F694E1-7A45-4D1E-BB26-6F0A929A135D/MTWMonth/p5>";
})
```

Comment: Have you found any solution/explanation for this?

Answer (score -1):

Have you performed the fetch without an error?

```
NSError *error;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

If you have, check that `ourMeeting` is in `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects`

Comment: Well, there has been no error and self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects does indeed contain my object. Now I'm wondering on what's next...

Comment: Are you sure it's the same object and not 2 objects with the same data? You can check by calling `[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects containsItem:ourMeeting]` and see if that returns true.

Comment: Thing is, it **does** return true. I've double checked, even triple checked it

Comment: Have you checked inside that same method where you create `ourPath`? Maybe something set `self.fetchedResultsController` to nil?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange too, but no, it's totally fine, FRC is non nil.

Comment: Hmm I'd want to debug this.. If you could put some of this code of GitHub somewhere with this issue I could try to reproduce it

Answer (score -1):

Your fetched results controller is set up without predicates so that it fetches **all** meetings, therefore the meeting in question should be in the FRC's `fetchedObjects`.

Within the limits of the provided code you can check:

- is `targetDay` nil?
- is `targetDay.dayMeetings` an empty `NSSet`?
- is the fetched results controller nil?
- did you forget to call `performFetch` on the FRC?
- did you check that the FRC's **context** is the same as the one from which you get the object?
- are you getting object from the same fetched results controller you are using to place it?

Comment: As stated in the comment to the similar answer, surprisingly, `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` contains `ourMeeting`. FRC is not nil and I've performed fetch. Moreover, I've edited my post with an example console print out of the MTWDay object.

Comment: Please also see my edits about context and fetched results controller.

Comment: I'll double check with the context, thanks for the idea!